# tfsbuild --- how to output to 2 different sources

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I using tfsbuild for a while. It's been working well till now as per our current sructure, but now the situation is different. I know tfs build outputs to the one mentioned in sln file plus builddropbox. But my concern is i want to output the binaries of a each solution file to its different directories rather than into one flat structure.  Is there a way we can do this. I am using tfsbuild and modifying the  build definition per requirements.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this post,

http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build-part-2/

Comment: thanks for your response, i still need the flat output structure as it helps me in resolving as second source for references. The issue is i have around 16 solution files and each solution file has multiple projects associated. I am still using the old definition files as i am not to conversant with the new process template yet. Is there a way where i can make some changes in build definition project file to achieve what i am trying to do.